# Set the title for bash Terminal on mac OS X to current working directory

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

I know they have been asking a lot of this question and I got it worked perfectly, but one thing I don't understand is why this is different.

```
 #This will show the full path (/usr/bin)
 PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${PWD}\007"'


 #This will set to the directory name only (bin)
 PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${PWD##*/}\007"'
```

The problem I have here is that I want to use the second one, but when I open a new tap it will go back to the default working directory, whereas the first one will keep the same working directory if I open another tap which I want that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange. Maybe it has to do with when the pattern-expansion takes place in bash's order of processing.

Something like `PROMPT_COMMAND='BASED=${PWD##*/} echo -ne "\033]0;$BASED\007"' might do the trick.

EDIT: That didn't work? Maybe this will

```
set_prompt () {
    BASE_PATH="${PWD##*/}"
    echo -ne "\033]0;$BASE_PATH\007"
}

PROMPT_COMMAND=set_prompt
```

Comment: It doesn't work at all :(

Comment: No? I'm pretty sure the issue is when bash expands the pattern. (what /else/ could be different in your examples?) So play with different things. But then, I could be wrong, also.

Comment: it works this way, but strange when opening a new tab then it will go back to the default working directory :(

Comment: Wait, the original tab changes its title when you open a new tab?

Comment: yes it does change, but when I open a new tab it will go back to the default one when I open terminal

Comment: Are you expecting the new tab to keep your changed title? I'm afraid it doesn't work that way. Simple answer: ANSI codes were invented before tabs.

Comment: no what I'm trying to do is that when I open a new tab it should be the same working directory after I changed it not going back to where I start (default working directory)

Comment: Oh. That has nothing to do with bash itself, then. It's specific to the particular terminal emulator you're using. (E.g., `gnome-terminal` dose work this way.)

Comment: (If you retag as Mac or OSX, you might attract someone who knows about that specific terminal emulator.

Comment: In mac they have that option but it doesn't even work :(

Comment: It sounds like Mac's terminal emulator relies on the title containing the full path in order to get new tabs right. But I couldn't imagine doing something so buggy!

Comment: I guess I'm going to use iTerm instead :(